# NtOpenFile() with ConDrv device shows 0xC0000005 error

Tags: winapi, console

I'm mimicking the connection between `conhost.exe` and `condrv.sys` driver. So I copied the code from conhost.exe in a simple C file and compiled it. But `NtOpenFile()` always shows `0xc0000005` error. Here is the code snippet.

```c
RtlInitUnicodeString(&DestinationString, L"\\Device\\ConDrv\\Server");
ObjectAttributes.Length = sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES);
ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory = 0;
ObjectAttributes.Attributes = OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE;
ObjectAttributes.ObjectName = &DestinationString;
ObjectAttributes.SecurityDescriptor = 0;
status = NtOpenFile(&Handle, GENERIC_ALL, &ObjectAttributes, &IoStatusBlock, 0, 0);
```

How to modify that code to work properly? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @KenWhite: 0xC0000005 is an access violation, i.e. an attempt to read from/write to/execute a memory address, that cannot be read from/written to/executed.

Comment: you forget init `SecurityQualityOfService` - faster of all this give access violation.

Comment: better init it as `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &DestinationString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };`

Comment: FYI, the interface between condrv.sys and conhost.exe is completely private. Microsoft is free to change everything about this whenever it wants. In Windows 8+, condrv.sys executes conhost.exe and, at least in Windows 10, passes the inherited handle for "Server" on the command line. So they could actually at some point make the `IRP_MJ_CREATE` dispatch function for this case (i.e. `condrv!CdCreateServer`) always fail with access denied (0xC0000022) when called from user mode. What's your end goal here? It seems dubious and fragile.

Comment: @eryksun Yes sir, you're right about that c-22 error. I just want to know how console works from inside (not from just articles).

Comment: I suspect it's simpler to use kernel-mode and user-mode debuggers to inspect, reverse engineer, and document how condrv.sys, kernelbase.dll, and conhost.exe work in concert to implement the console connection and API in Windows 8+. I'm not deeply interested in the details, which, as I said, are private and subject to change radically from version to version. I'm waiting for Microsoft to adapt condrv.sys into a public pseudo-console API, so Windows will no longer need hacks such as winpty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @RbMm for that advice. The `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` struct is defined as:

```
typedef struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {
    ULONG Length;
    HANDLE RootDirectory;
    PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    ULONG Attributes;
    PVOID SecurityDescriptor;
    PVOID SecurityQualityOfService;
} OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;
typedef OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES *POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;
```

The error shows because I forget to make `SecurityQualityOfService` zero. So `NtOpenFile()` grabs the `SecurityQualityOfService` value from whatever left over in memory. And it shows `0xC0000005` aka. Memory Access Violation. I add `ObjectAttributes.SecurityQualityOfService = 0;` and it works.

---

The correct way, however, is to use [`InitializeObjectAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/ntdef/nf-ntdef-initializeobjectattributes) in order to initialize this structure.

Comment: BTW, you can always just `InitializeObjectAttributes` instead of manually setting each field of structure yourself. The macro does it for you, you just pass as arguments. It is defined in `winternl.h` for user-mode. IMO, looks cleaner using that macro.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR that's exactly -- and always has been -- the way to go. You should write it up as an answer. It's not as hacky, but it's the way every kernel mode developer will learn it.